# How to expect a custom error to be thrown with jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have this custom error implemented in TypeScript:

```js
export class UserNotFoundError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('User not found');
    this.name = 'UserNotFoundError';
  }
}
```

and I throw it when the user doesn't exists on the DB:

```js
if (await this.userRepository.findById(userId) === null)
      throw new UserNotFoundError();
```

I have a test case (implemented with Jest) that expects this error with `toThrow(UserNotFoundError)`, I also tried with `toBeInstanceOf(UserNotFoundError)`.

```js
it ('Should throw an UserNotFoundError', async () => {

    await expect(() => {
      return createPost.exec('My content', 'no-user-with-this-id');
    }).rejects.toThrow(UserNotFoundError);

});
```

However, jest is receiving an Error instance instead of UserNotFoundError:
[image: Error image]

How to solve it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8279

Comment: Thank you!! It worked adding `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, UserNotFoundError.prototype)` at the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a breaking change on TypeScript, described here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work

it's suggested to "manually adjust the prototype immediately after any super(...) calls". Then to solve the problem with Jest the constructor needs to be as the following:

```js
export class UserNotFoundError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('User not found');
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, UserNotFoundError.prototype);

    this.name = 'UserNotFoundError';
  }
}
```

Now the test passes!